# Summernote - Custom dropdown for ordered and unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, summernote

I am using Summernote editor v0.8.9 for quite a long time. I have created a custom dropdown button for Ordered List and Unordered List by using below code

```
let orderedList = function (context)
        {
            let ui = $.summernote.ui;

            // create button
            let button = ui.buttonGroup([
                ui.button({
                className: 'dropdown-toggle',
                contents: '<i class="fa fa-list-ol"/><span class="note-icon-caret"></span>',
                container: false,
                tooltip: 'Ordered List',
                data: {
                    toggle: 'dropdown'
                }
                }),
                ui.dropdown({
                    className: 'dropdown-style',
                    contents: "<ol style='list-style-type:none' class='ordered-list'><li data-value='1'>1</li><li data-value='1' style='display: none;'>1)</li><li data-value='I'>I</li><li data-value='A'>A</li><li data-value='a)' style='display: none;'>a)</li><li data-value='a'>a</li><li data-value='i'>i</li></ol>",
                    callback: function ($dropdown) {
                        $dropdown.find('li').each(function () {
                            $(this).click(function() {
                                selectedListType = orderedListMap[$(this).attr('data-value')];
                                $(context).summernote('editor.insertOrderedList');
                            });
                        });
                    }
                })
            ]);

            return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
        };
```

And also I get the dropdown attached to the toolbar as shown in the image

[image]

I have changed some code in the summernote.js to change the list style type after clicking on the dropdown item.

I am adding following code in the Bullet.prototype.wrapList method as follows

```
//for bullets and numbering style
if (selectedListType != 'NA') {
     listNode.setAttribute('style', 'list-style-type:' + selectedListType);
 }
```

I have also added the following code in the method "function replace(node, nodeName)" of "dom" object.

```
//for bullets and numbering style
if ((nodeName == 'OL' || nodeName == 'UL' ) && selectedListType != 'NA') {
    $(newNode).css('list-style-type', selectedListType);
}
```

When I click on the dropdown item I am calling below code.

```
$(context).summernote('editor.insertOrderedList');
```

At first instance everything is working fine. I can change ordered list to unordered list as well as to other types of lists. But the problem arises when I am trying to create a new list. When I try to create a new list below the existing list (note : after double entering new line, existing list closes, hence a new list is created after double entering new line),

[image]

the focus does not stay on the current line. Instead it goes to the old list and old list style (Ordered/unordered) is getting changed.

[image]

I have also kept the default UL/OL in the toolbar for deugging and I can see that the document.selection() in the method WrappedRange.prototype.nativeRange is giving proper selection for default UL/OL but is giving wrong selection for my dropdown UL/OL.

Please help.

Let me know if any info is needed from my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

The problem was with the custom dropdown I created.

The dropdown needs to be in the following structure in the 'contents' attribute inside 'ui.dropdown'

```
<li>
    <a href="#"></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#"></a>
</li>
```

'a' tag inside 'li' tag